# Error archiving from Xcode project

Tags: mojave, xcode

I am unable to archive from an Xcode project. The build is failing with the following error:

[image]

How do I resolve it?

Comment: The error appears pretty self explanatory. What have you tried so far to resolve the issue?

Comment: I have tried to archive into a ipa